# Wrong days' initials in OBIEE Datepicker

Tags: calendar, datepicker, oracle10g, prompt, obiee

Where does OBIEE store/get the days for the datepicker ? In english that is correct, but in another language there are two wrong.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GZx3.png)

It should be "S T Q Q S S D"

Answer (score 0):

You could try the messages directory, and adding a custom message to over-rule it. (A google search for *obiee 10g custom messages* should help with that).

Unfortunately 10g is way out of support now so it's probably not worth raising it with Oracle. I guess you could still try though.